# Documentation comments for properties of positional records in C#

Tags: c#, record, xml-comments, c#-9.0

If I have a positional record like this:

```
public record Version(int Major, int Minor);
```

it seems that I can only provide a `<summary>` documentation, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Version record
/// </summary>
public record Version(int Major, int Minor);
```

Is it possible to document the `Major` and `Minor` properties (possibly constructor arguments as well) while keeping the short record syntax?

Comment: This is [still under development](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44571)

Comment: Not sure but try this

/// <param name="Major">The major.</param>    
/// <param name="Minor">The minor.</param>

Or install GhostDoc, a great plugin who auto-comment your code

Comment: Does typing ```///``` and hitting space generate the XML comment with the parameter? Which visual studio version are you using? That works for me (vs 19, version 16.7.1) and I don't have ghostDoc installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From .NET 6.0.300 and up, 'param' docs on the primary constructor now automatically propagate to the 'summary' doc on the property.

Original answer below.

---

As canton7 points out this is [still under development](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44571).

The best workaround right now to document the property and the parameters is to define the property explicitly, whilst keeping the record positional:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Version record
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Major">Major constructor parameter</param>
/// <param name="Minor">Minor constructor paramater</param>
public record Version(int Major, int Minor)
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Major Property
    /// </summary>
    public int Major { get; init; } = Major;

    /// <summary>
    /// Minor property
    /// </summary>
    public int Minor { get; init; } = Minor;
}
```

This is slightly shorter than defining the constructor yourself, but more usefully, once support is added you can move the documentation to the primary constructor whilst knowing that this won't change the generated code in any way. Also it is necessary to do it this way if you want to inherit from another positional record.

Comment: and the new issue to follow: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52663

Answer (score 2):

As of .NET SDK 6.0.300 and Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2, this is accomplished by [using the `<param name="property-name">parameter summary</param>` tag](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52663#issuecomment-919488488). Thus the following would accomplish the desired result:

```
/// <summary>
/// Version record
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Major">Major version</param>
/// <param name="Minor">Minor version</param>
public record Version(int Major, int Minor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can document it like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Version record
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Major">Major version</param>
/// <param name="Minor">Minor version</param>
public record Version(int Major, int Minor);
```

And then you have the documentation while using it in-code :

[image: Documentation]

Comment: This doesn't add documentation to the property, however.

Comment: I'm wondering why someone would like to document and integer.
If you need more documentation, you set a class property where the class is documented.

Comment: @canton7 3 years on and it seems that it does now.

Comment: So it does! I can't edit that comment any more, but yes, life has improved.